# Fatal error (11)Segmentation fault when trying to enter gdb mode in emacs, what's wrong?

Tags: linux, emacs, gdb

What does the following segmentation fault mean?

```
Fatal error (11)Segmentation fault
```

What is a segmentation fault, and what can cause it to happen?

The issue arrises once I type, `Mx gdb` into Emacs,

The inputs are shown in this [picture](http://i1271.photobucket.com/albums/jj624/bigmeowOoO/before-enter-gdb-mode.jpg) the output is shown [here](http://i1271.photobucket.com/albums/jj624/bigmeowOoO/after-i-press-enter.jpg).

more details:

[a]: i build emacs 24.1 on centos 5.3 from source, this build cannot enter gdb mode

[b]: also i build emacs 24.1 on debian 5.0, it can use gdb mode without error

so i really don't know what happened that i cannot use gdb mode in emacs 24.1 on centos 5.3:(

Comment: you mean i should do some operation to accept answers once others answered my questions, right?

Comment: @mathematician1975 which information do you need, just tell me:)

Comment: It may be an Emacs bug. Report it here to get help: http://news.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.devel

Comment: @Tom why not post the emacs maillist directly:)

Comment: This is the emacs development mailing list. Segfaults will interest them.

Answer (score 2):

To debug Emacs, if you built it yourself, change to the project directory, then do:

```
$ gdb ./src/emacs
$ (gdb) set logging file ~/emacs-errors.log
$ (gdb) r -q
<... get to the point where error happens ...>
$ (gdb) bt full
```

Then, when you send the bug report, use the ~/emacs-errors.log file (gdb will print all errors into it).

Also note that you will need to configure it to preserve the debug information when you compile it. To do that,

```
$ CFLAGS='-O0 -ggdb -g3' ./configure --enable-checking --enable-asserts
```

and then recompile.