# where i should set breakpoints when i debug emacs?

Tags: debugging, emacs, gdb, segmentation-fault

the problem is not to debug c, php, python, etc in emacs, but debug emacs itself.
i have confronted with a segmentation fault error when i try to enter gdb mode in emacs using 
Mx gdb Enter

now i have build emacs with debug info, and have load it using "gdb emacs" command.

l command shows the source code of emacs,
now my problem is how to debug emacs? where i should set that breakpoint?
howto find the origin of segmentation fault using gdb?

the following is a screenshot about what i have did now, so any suggestions how i should debug emacs? and where to set break points?

http://i1271.photobucket.com/albums/jj624/bigmeowOoO/emacs_where-i-should-set-breakpoint-when-debug-emacs.jpg

Comment: just run it in the debugger. if it segfaults then the debugger should catch it. http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/gdbtut/gdbsegfault.html

Comment: This question is a continuation of that one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11921100/fatal-error-11segmentation-fault-when-trying-to-enter-gdb-mode-in-emacs-what. Rather than starting a new question, you should generally just edit the one you've already asked. Then again, you've asked the original question so badly, you should probably just delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> howto find the origin of segmentation fault using gdb?

Don't set any breakpoints (yet). Simply use `run` command. That will start `emacs` running (under GDB control).

In that `emacs`, do `M-x gdb`. `emacs` will crash (if you are lucky), and you'll get `(gdb)` prompt right at the crash point.

From there, use `gdb` to examine the state of `emacs` at crash point. Figure out which variables have wrong values, etc. Then figure out where these variables are set, set the breakpoints there, and repeat (just as you would if you were debugging any other program -- there is nothing special about `emacs` being your buggy program).

P.S. Please don't post pictures where a simple text cut/paste will convey *exactly* the same information.